# Number format Exception while trying to take the data

Tags: java, exception, input

When i try to run this below code it is not even letting me to enter the input and throwing NumberFormatException. Can anyone please help me i reviewed similar kind of questions but didn't got the proper answer.

```
public static String takeFieldName() {
            String fullfield = "";
            //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter number of fields: ");
            //int nofields = sc.nextInt();
            int nofields = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

            String[] fname = new String[nofields];
            //sc.skip("/n");
            System.out.println("Specify fields with names");

            for(int i=0;i<fname.length;i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter field :"+(i+1));
                fname[i] = sc.nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println("Fields are:");
            for(String s:fname) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            return UserDAO.toCSV(fname);
    }
```

**Exception is:**

```
Enter tablename: 
manikanta
table already exists
Enter tablename: 
salamankhan
Enter number of fields: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at connections.UserDAO.takeFieldName(UserDAO.java:53)
    at connections.Application.main(Application.java:11)
```

**When i use nextInt() to take the size of an array the output i'm getting is:**

```
Enter tablename: 
salmankhan
Enter number of fields: 
2
Specify fields with names
Enter field :1
Enter field :2
```

Where i need to take field 1 and field 2 separately.

the takeTableName() is another function in that method i'm calling takeFieldName() if the table doesn't exist in the database it will call takeFieldName() method to take field names. in that i used next() method to take the table name

Comment: you are trying to parse an empty String into a numeric value, but an empty String is not a numeric value.

Comment: then how do i pass the number to the array? when i use nextInt() it is not working properly. Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: you should enter the number , provide the numeric value, instead of pressing enter key.

Comment: It is not even letting me to enter anything. after taking the table name i want to take the size of the array so i need to pass integer to that. after entering the table name itself it is throwing the exception

Comment: @Mars_rider you have no number. Why not use a JOptionPane dialog? It 'll make it less likely to have invalid input. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Comment: About your current code: where do you enter the table name? why don't you use sc.nextInt() to read your number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/5221149)

Comment: the takeTableName() is another function in that method i'm calling takeFieldName() if the table doesn't exist in the database it will call takeFieldName()  method to take field names. in that i used next() method to take the table name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: wait i'll edit the question please check it after a min

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
int nofields = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

into

```
int nofields = sc.nextInt());
```

Comment: that would, most likely, result in the same issue.